# Как сделать временный доступ для пользователя?

Tags: android, авторизация, права-доступа

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты, ограничения доступа. На пример отправил пользователю ключ доступа, он добавил и активировал на какой то срок. Время истекло, доступ закрылся. И ключ надо одноразовый. Я это вижу как то так. Может есть варианты и проще. Хелп. Или как проконтролировать каждого, кто зарегился.

Comment: Из вариантов - добавить привязку по id устройства (для этого пользователь должен указать вам свой id, можно так же залить файл на пастебин и редактировать кол-во id) или сделать сделать авторизацию через гугл

Comment: а чем стандартная подписка не устраивает?

Comment: Я решил, немного костыльным способом, через Firebase, создаю пароль, потом изменяю, так же есть авторизация, где буду блокировать. Вообщем, как то вот так. Ограничивать доступ по времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно сложно такую систему представить. Если речь идет о доступе к каким-то ресурсам, и под ключем подразумевается токен, то можно посмотреть в сторону [access_token](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0) и refresh_token. Если у вас распространение ключей происходит по другому алгоритму, то например можно использовать SharedPreference. Суть будет такой - вы передаете пользователю ключ, и после того как он принимается программой, нужно записывать в память переменную которая будет отображать момент времени когда ключ протухнет:

```
final long millisToAdd = 7_200_000; //два часа
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+millisToAdd;
SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
prefs.edit().putLong("endTime", endTime ).apply();
```

дальше получаем при запуске активности или где вам там нужно проверить протухлость ключа и сравниваем текущее utc время с тем что сохранено:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis()>prefs.getLong("time", 0)){
// ключ устарел
}
```

[вот статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/456188/) про доступ к апи по ключам. Вам нужно будет сделать двойную проверку- у себя и у пользователя. Если пользователь каким-то образом смог повторно выслать вам ключ который должен был протухнуть то вы должны у себя так же проверять валидность ключа. А за использование на разных устройствах - да ключ можно использовать и на других устройствах если вы или пользователь его перебросит на другое устройство. Но он все равно его сможет использовать пока проверка на вашей стороне сообщает что ключ свежий. Если вы сможете сделать такую проверку то можно не использовать время протухания на стороне клиента а проверять у себя как это делается на серверах. Либо сделать две проверки что точно не навредит ;)

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы код, который я дам пользователю, не передавался кому то еще. То есть, используется один раз и все.на сколько это головная боль, для меня?

Comment: Ну все зависит от того как вы его будете передавать, проверка которую я предлагаю вам рассмотреть не зависит от способа передачи)

Comment: То есть, человек не сможет использовать этот же код на другом устройстве?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что для этого устройства он устарел, а для других нет, проще тогда удалить приложение будет и переустановить, используя старый ключ

Comment: Если вы сможете передать код на другое устройство то сможет, но способ проверки изложенный выше привязывается к устройству, так же стоит учитывать что при переустановке приложения данные о времени протухания ключа трутся, в таких ситуациях нужно смотреть в сторону апи и ключей доступа

Comment: Вы должны делать две проверки на стороне юзера и у себя, если пользователь передает тухлый ключ то вы ему должны это сообщить

Comment: Ладно, буду еще думать )) спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него. Так же обратите внимание на мою правку, может она вам поможет :)

Comment: Могу тупить(сори), а чему равен SP pref?

Comment: Здесь настройки приложения хранятся, вот туториал есть http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php